# How can I break down this servlet.java into more classes?

Tags: java, class, servlets

I'm using GAE, which runs Jetty, and Java. I have a working servlet in one monolithic java file. I would like to start breaking it down into different classes.

At this point I really just want to place most of the code into another Class and call it with the idea of generating different webpages in different classes depending on the input.

Right now, in /Servlet.java, I have:

```
package webapp
        public class servlet extends HttpServlet {
           public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
           ...
           try {
               temp.process(root, resp.getWriter());
           } catch (TemplateException e) {
               throw new IOException("Error while processing Freemarker template", e);
           } 
        }
```

When I try to create a new class with:

```
public classA {

public void generatePageA() {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        ...
        resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");

        try {
        temp.process(root, resp.getWriter());
    } catch (TemplateException e) {
        throw new IOException("Error while processing Freemarker template", e);
    } 

    }


}
```

Then back in servlet.java I try to call the function in ClassA with

```
ClassA.doGet();
```

But I get syntax error requesting identifiers after tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for calling ClassA.doGet(); you need to make it Static,

```
public classA {

    public static void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        try {
            temp.process(root, resp.getWriter());
        } catch (TemplateException e) {
           throw new IOException("Error while processing Freemarker template", e);
        } 
    }
}
```

you also have to pass the arguments like :

```
package webapp
public class servlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
        ClassA.doGet(req,resp);
    }
}
```

If you want more informations post the complete stack trace, so we can provide better support

Comment: Thanks. This worked except that I had to get rid of the "static" from "pulic static void doGet" in the servlet class.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your doGet() method starts before your generatePageA() method ends. And ClassA.doGet() is a static reference to a method. the method either needs to be static, or you need to instantiate the class object like so

```
new ClassA().doGet();
```

Working in an IDE like eclipse will show you these errors live, and it usually offers suggestions on how to fix.
Hope that helps

Comment: I went with the static reference. But what is considered best practice here? To instantiate the class object or to use static references?

Comment: Best practice wise, if it performs a service and stores no class level variables, it should be static and you should end the class name with Util or Helper.